# How to Navigating to other Namespaces in clojure "lein repl"?

Tags: clojure

There is two file in a lein project a:core.clj and a.clj. core.clj have a function "foo",and a.clj have a function "add",which add two number,in folder a,enter

```
lein repl
```

in default,show me

```
a.core=>
```

I want to call function add in a.clj,use command "ns" or "in-ns",can switch to

```
a.a=>
```

but can't call add,

```
(add 1 2)
```

or

```
(a.a/add 1 2)
```

both tell me can't find add

ofcourse I can use (load-file "a.clj") in folder a,then I can use

```
(a.a/add 1 2)
```

but how to do it in "lein repl"?Thanks!

I have read https://clojure.org/guides/repl/navigating_namespaces, but can't fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a project that looks like so:

```bash
-rw------- 1 alan alan 873 Sep 25 03:18 project.clj
-rw------- 1 alan alan 201 Jan  4 20:21 src/clj/demo/core.clj
-rw------- 1 alan alan  50 Jan  4 20:20 src/clj/demo/fred.clj
```

The source files look like:

```
(ns demo.core)

(defn talk []
  (prn :yabba))

(defn -main [& args]
  (prn :main--enter)
  (println "Hello World!")
  (prn :main--leave))
```

and

```
(ns demo.fred)

(defn foo [& args]
  (prn :foo))
```

You can manipulate it in the REPL using the `require` function as follows.  Note that this is different from the `:require` clause in the `(ns ...)` form.

Using `(require ...)` in the REPL will cause the namespace to be loaded.  AFTER the new NS is loaded, you may use `in-ns` to switch from the current NS to the new one (i.e. from `demo.core` to `demo.fred`).

```clj
~/expr/demo > lein repl 
Clojure 1.11.1

demo.core=> (talk)
:yabba
nil
demo.core=> (require '[demo.fred :as fred])
nil
demo.core=> (fred/foo)
:foo
nil
demo.core=> Bye for now!
```

and for completeness:

```
(defproject demo "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :dependencies [
                 [org.clojure/clojure "1.11.1"]
                 [prismatic/schema "1.2.1"]
                 [tupelo "22.08.03"]
                 ]
  :global-vars {*warn-on-reflection* false}
  :main ^:skip-aot demo.core

  :source-paths ["src/clj"]
  :java-source-paths ["src/java"]
  :test-paths ["test/clj"]
  :target-path "target/%s"
  :compile-path "%s/class-files"
  :clean-targets [:target-path]

  :jvm-opts ["-Xms500m" "-Xmx2g"]
  )
```

Please see [this template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template) for my favorite way to set up a new project in Clojure.